# Why can I mutate a let constant with inout parameter when using try?

Tags: swift, pointers, immutability, inout

This will fail to compile with the error:

> Immutable value 'self.constantValue' must not be passed inout

```
class Test {
    let constantValue: String = ""


    init() {
        Test.makeABC(&constantValue)
    }

    static func makeABC(_ string: inout String) {
        string = "ABC"
    }
}
```

However this will compile and actually mutate the let constant.

```
class Test {
    let constantValue: String = ""


    init() {
        try? Test.makeABC(&constantValue)
    }

    static func makeABC(_ string: inout String) throws {
        string = "ABC"
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this works and if it is intended behavior?

I have filed a bug https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8368

Comment: That looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @MartinR Interestingly, this behavior is confined to `init`. Move the `try?` to a normal method and the compiler rejects that one too.

Comment: Fixed typo  AnotherTest to just Test

Comment: Congratulations on finding a great edge case! We always like it when that happens. Well done.